# Grails jQuery submit g:uploadForm

Tags: jquery, grails

I want to use jQuery to submit a g:uploadForm. I tried

```
$('#idOfForm').submit();
```

and it didn't work. Is there a better way to do this than to declare a hidden submit button and trigger a click on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `id` to submit the form use `class` like:

```
$('.classOfForm').submit();
```

or `name` like:

```
$("[name='nameOfForm']").submit();
```

`id` used for sending `id` of some `domain instance`.

Comment: I tried the class method and it worked. Thank you. Up til now I thought the only difference between class and id was the name uniqueness but I didn't know they functionally differed as well.